# Codeigniter and Jtable plugin - An error occured while communicating to the server

Tags: codeigniter, jtable

I have 2 php files that will generate a jtable plugin which when I run without using code igniter works perfectly. But when I put it in codeigniter that's the time the error will show up. here is my file hierarchy

```
 application/
      ...
      views/
           system_admin/
                 PersonActions.php
                 view_systemadmin_manageprojects.php
```

When I run it, the base interface of jtable shows up but without a data plus an error.

I have this code in the view file which calls the other php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of News and Events',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=list',
                createAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=create',
                updateAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=delete'
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI framework use MVC (Model, View, Controller) pattern and you have to follow it, here you are sending requests direct to PHP PersonActions class, try to create controller with name personAction and call your actions

```
class PersonActions extends CI_Controller{

   function listRecord(){

   }

   function create(){

   }  

   function update(){

   }

   function delete(){

   } 

}
```

now javascript

```
//Prepare jTable

var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>"; // in you html as global before calling jtable script 

$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Table of News and Events',
    actions: {
        listAction: base_url+'PersonActions/list',
        createAction: base_url+'PersonActions/create',
        updateAction: base_url+'PersonActions/update',
        deleteAction: base_url+'PersonActions/delete'
    },
```

Comment: `CI framework use MVC` It doesn't. CI tries to implement MVC. It is a MVC-like framework. Sorry dude, I'm on `use strict` mode.